# Time Complexity Clarification

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

With the following algorithm (from Leetcode):

Given a non-empty string s and a dictionary wordDict containing a list of non-empty words, determine if s can be segmented into a space-separated sequence of one or more dictionary words. You may assume the dictionary does not contain duplicate words.

For example, given
s = "leetcode",
dict = ["leet", "code"].

Return true because "leetcode" can be segmented as "leet code".

The naive solution is given as follows:

```
public class Solution {
    public boolean wordBreak(String s, List<String> wordDict) {
        return word_Break(s, new HashSet(wordDict), 0);
    }
    public boolean word_Break(String s, Set<String> wordDict, int start) {
        if (start == s.length()) {
            return true;
        }
        for (int end = start + 1; end <= s.length(); end++) {
            if (wordDict.contains(s.substring(start, end)) && word_Break(s, wordDict, end)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The time complexity is listed as O(n^n) because that's how big the recursive tree goes. I totally agree that the last level of the recursion tree has N^N elements, but doesn't the one before that level have N^(N-1)? So we're looking at N^N + N^(N-1) + N^(N-2)... resulting in a much higher time complexity correct?

Comment: hmmm, maybe make `word_Break` private? Also, `N^N + N^(N-1) + ...` is a *geometric series* which gives `O(N^(N+1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we talk about time complexity and inparticular, Big-O notation, we only need to reference the fastest growing factor. Hence you may be right with it being `N^N + N^(N-1)...` which we write as `TIME(N^N + N^(N-1)...)` however this is equivalent to `O(N^N)` since `N^N` is the fastest growing factor.

For example, I could have some algorithm which runs in `TIME(N^2 + N + 123)`, since `N^2` is the fastest growing part, we just say `TIME(N^2 + N + 123) = O(N^2)`.

Comment: Hmm. But in the same vein that N * (N-1) * (N-2) results in a time complexity of O(N^2) [and therefore a higher factor], how do we know not to account for something similar here?

Comment: Not quite. Your example would be N^3.

Comment: There's a significant difference between `+` and `*` so "in the same vein" doesn't  quite apply

Comment: @gue No, given he only said, N * (N-1) * (N-2) != N * (N - 1) * (N - 2) * .. * 2 * 1 = N!

Comment: @Sunny We know because of math. See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation article. A quote from it: *If f(x) is a sum of several terms, if there is one with largest growth rate, it can be kept, and all others omitted.*

Comment: Oops I didn't mean to multiply my factors-- I meant N + (N-1) + (N-2) which is O(N^2)

Comment: But I think I understand the difference -- in the above all the N's have the same power and so no term dominates the others

Comment: Am I correct in that it is N^N + N^(N-1) + N^(N-2)...?

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with a simple *recurrence relation* for the *upper bound* of the time complexity function (i.e. assuming that it loops the whole way without finding a match):

[image]

Here `i` is `start` and `N` is `s.length()`. Each term corresponds to:

- 1st: Recursive calls to `word_Break` with `start = end`, where `end` is `j`
- 2nd: Call to `wordDict.contains` with a substring of length `end - start + 1`.

  Now since `wordDict` is a hashset, this call is `O(L)` where `L` is the length of the input word (because we need to copy the substring and hash it)

Expanding:

[image]

(Last step from Wolfram alpha)

Which is totally different to what your source says.

---

As added support for my answer, lets do a numerical test:

```
uint64_t T(uint32_t N, uint32_t start)
{
   if (start >= N) return 1;
   uint64_t sum = 0;
   for (uint32_t end = start + 1; end <= N; end++)
      sum += (end - start + 1) + T(N, end);
   return sum;
}
```

Results:

```
N        T(N)
-----------------
1        3 
2        9 
3        22 
4        49 
5        104 
6        215 
7        438 
8        885 
9        1780 
10       3571 
11       7154 
12       14321 
13       28656 
14       57327 
15       114670 
16       229357 
17       458732 
18       917483 
19       1834986 
20       3669993 
21       7340008 
22       14680039 
23       29360102 
24       58720229 
25       117440484 
26       234880995 
27       469762018 
28       939524065 
29       1879048160 
30       3758096351 
31       7516192734 
32       15032385501 
33       30064771036 
34       60129542107
```

Log-scale plot of time complexity:

[image]

As you can see this is linear, which means that the time complexity is of the form `a^N` and *not* `N^N`.

---

By contrast, `T(N) = O(N^N)` would give the following plot:

[image]

Which is not linear and grows *much* faster (note the numbers on the vertical axis).

Answer (score 2):

Since terms N^(N-2), N^(N-3), ... N^(1) are smaller than N^(N-1), we can deduce that N^(N-1) + N^(N-2) + ... + N^1 is smaller than N*N^(N-1) = N^N and hence your sum is less than 2*N^N = O(N^N)